# Show additional info when an ItemOverlay is clicked in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've implemented and Android MapView with some OverlayItems and now I'd like to show and dialog like this when one of them is clicked

[image]

I basically need to show the name and address of the place. Is there an easy way of doing this or I have to manually create a new drawable for the item with the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used MapView Balloons in the past to accomplish this:

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons